# Bootstrap align to right with form-inline in row

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How it is:

[image]
How it should be:

[image]

Currently second component is pushed to right however its content is aligned to left. I tried to add `float-right` class but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     Some component here
    </div>
    <!--Content of this element should be aligned to right-->
    <div class="col-auto ml-auto">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <label>Some label</label>
        <input class="form-control" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <label>Other longer label</label>
        <input class="form-control" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add an image, or explain with a graph the layout you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have added `style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end"` to following element `<div class="form-inline">` and it worked how I want.